# InfoWindow showing in wrong place

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have little problem with my webpage. When I'm trying to show InfoWindow on marker. That windows shows on the top left corner of a map instead of on the marker. Just like in screen below:
[image]

Here is my script I use for placing markers and using InfoWindows.

```
var infowindow;
function point(name, lat, long) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.lat = ko.observable(lat);
    self.long = ko.observable(long);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
    title: name,
    map: map,
    draggable: true
});

//if you need the poition while dragging
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function () {
    var pos = marker.getPosition();
    this.lat(pos.lat());
    this.long(pos.lng());
}.bind(this));

//if you just need to update it when the user is done dragging
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
    var pos = marker.getPosition();
    this.lat(pos.lat());
    this.long(pos.lng());
}.bind(this));

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "empty" });
    console.log(marker.title);
    infowindow.setContent(marker.name);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

}.bind(this));


}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55, 11),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var viewModel = {
    points: ko.observableArray([
        new point('Test1', 55, 11),
        new point('Test2', 56, 12),
        new point('Test3', 57, 13)])

};
function addPoint() {
    viewModel.points.push(new point('a', 58, 14));
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

here all on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24q8n/

Comment: You should provide your entire code, and if possible a jsFiddle.

Comment: Added! -> http://jsfiddle.net/24q8n/

Comment: `marker.name` does not exist. You are trying to add it with `setContent`. That gives an error and places your infowindow in the wrong place. Use `marker.title` or something that is not `undefined`.

Comment: What are you trying to do in your drag and dragend listeners? I don't get it.

Comment: Those fragments wre for simple learning about Knockout.js. I forgot to delete them ;)

Comment: Ok. As suggested above, replace marker.name by marker.title. I would not use info windows on mouseover events but if you do so, I would suggest to use a infowindow.close() on mouseout event. I would only use the info windows on click.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580923/infowindow-on-marker-using-markerclusterer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `marker.name` which is `undefined`.
So you are assigning undefined to `setContent` what apparently stops the `infoWindow` from working and ends up in the top left corner.
Remove `infowindow.setContent(marker.name)` or replace it with something that does have a value like `marker.title`. Or define `marker.name` when you define `var marker = ...`:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
    title: name,
    name: name, // define the name so setContent(marker.name) will work.
    map: map,
    draggable: true
});
```

Or remove the line that creates the problem:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "empty" });
    console.log(marker.title);
    // This line gives you the problem because marker.name is undefined.
    // infowindow.setContent(marker.name);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);    
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/24q8n/1/

Here is a working version of it.

Usually, an info window is a single object that you show and hide with updated content. What you are doing is recreating the InfoWindow object in your mouseover listener.

Instead of that, just define it outside your functions:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

and then just do:

```
infowindow.setContent(marker.title);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```