# How do i add infoWindow to this marker clustering code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add infoWindows to all the markers on this Google Marker Clustering map?

Below find code sample of Market Clustering without the infoWindows

This is simple Javascript with the Google Map API.

I need a info window with a link.

the var locations will be generated by php and mysql

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker Clustering</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      function initMap() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
        });

        // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        // Add some markers to the map.
        // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
        // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
        // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
        var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length]
          });
        });

        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
      }
      var locations = [
        {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
        {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
        {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124},
        {lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834},
        {lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968},
        {lat: -34.671264, lng: 150.863657},
        {lat: -35.304724, lng: 148.662905},
        {lat: -36.817685, lng: 175.699196},
        {lat: -36.828611, lng: 175.790222},
        {lat: -37.750000, lng: 145.116667},
        {lat: -37.759859, lng: 145.128708},
        {lat: -37.765015, lng: 145.133858},
        {lat: -37.770104, lng: 145.143299},
        {lat: -37.773700, lng: 145.145187},
        {lat: -37.774785, lng: 145.137978},
        {lat: -37.819616, lng: 144.968119},
        {lat: -38.330766, lng: 144.695692},
        {lat: -39.927193, lng: 175.053218},
        {lat: -41.330162, lng: 174.865694},
        {lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.439506},
        {lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.501315},
        {lat: -42.735258, lng: 147.438000},
        {lat: -43.999792, lng: 170.463352}
      ]
    </script>
    <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InfoWindow on Marker using MarkerClusterer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580923/infowindow-on-marker-using-markerclusterer)

Comment: The var locations will be generated by php and mysql